# Pandas: How to Compare Columns of Lists Row-wise in a DataFrame with Pandas (not for loop)?

Tags: python, pandas

**DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['gener'], ['gener'], ['system'], ['system'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum'], ['aluminum', 'toledo']], 'B': [['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter', 'system'], ['gutter', 'guard', 'system'], ['ohio', 'gutter'], ['gutter', 'toledo'], ['toledo', 'gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['gutter'], ['how', 'to', 'instal', 'aluminum', 'gutter'], ['aluminum', 'gutter'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'color'], ['aluminum', 'gutter'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'adrian', 'ohio'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'bowl', 'green', 'ohio'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'maume', 'ohio'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'perrysburg', 'ohio'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'tecumseh', 'ohio'], ['aluminum', 'gutter', 'toledo', 'ohio']]}, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

**What it Looks Like**

I have a dataframe with two columns of lists.

```
                     A                                      B
0              [gener]                               [gutter]
1              [gener]                               [gutter]
2             [system]                       [gutter, system]
3             [system]                [gutter, guard, system]
4             [gutter]                         [ohio, gutter]
5             [gutter]                       [gutter, toledo]
6             [gutter]                       [toledo, gutter]
7             [gutter]                               [gutter]
8             [gutter]                               [gutter]
9             [gutter]                               [gutter]
10          [aluminum]    [how, to, instal, aluminum, gutter]
11          [aluminum]                     [aluminum, gutter]
12          [aluminum]              [aluminum, gutter, color]
13          [aluminum]                     [aluminum, gutter]
14          [aluminum]       [aluminum, gutter, adrian, ohio]
15          [aluminum]  [aluminum, gutter, bowl, green, ohio]
16          [aluminum]        [aluminum, gutter, maume, ohio]
17          [aluminum]   [aluminum, gutter, perrysburg, ohio]
18          [aluminum]     [aluminum, gutter, tecumseh, ohio]
19  [aluminum, toledo]       [aluminum, gutter, toledo, ohio]
```

**Question**

If I have columns of lists, is there a pandas function that lets me operate on the entire array of lists to check for intersection and return either a boolean or the intersecting values as a new series?

For example, I'd like pandas to have an equivalent of this:

```
def intersection(df, col1, col2, return_type='boolean'):
    if return_type == 'boolean':
        df = df[[col1, col2]]
        s = []
        for idx in df.iterrows():
            s.append(any([phrase in idx[1][0] for phrase in idx[1][1]]))
        S = pd.Series(s)
        return S
    elif return_type == 'word':
        df = df[[col1, col2]]
        s = []
        for idx in df.iterrows():
            s.append(', '.join([word for word in list(set(idx[1][0]).intersection(set(idx[1][1])))]))
        S = pd.Series(s)
        return S

#Create column C in df
df['C'] = intersection(df, 'A', 'B', 'word')
```

... without having to write my own function or resort to for loops.  I feel like there must be an easier way to compare lists in two columns on the same row to see if they intersect.

**I can do it with `for` loops but it's ugly to me**

`for` loop to return a `boolean` series:

```
for idx in df.iterrows():
    any([phrase in idx[1][0] for phrase in idx[1][1]])
```

Produces:

```
False
False
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Or, finding the intersecting words using `set`s:

```
for idx in df.iterrows():
    ', '.join([word for word in list(set(idx[1][0]).intersection(set(idx[1][1])))])

''
''
'system'
'system'
'gutter'
'gutter'
'gutter'
'gutter'
'gutter'
'gutter'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'aluminum'
'toledo, aluminum'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To check if every item in `df.A` is contained in `df.B`:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: all(i in row.B for i in row.A), axis=1)
# OR: ~(df['A'].apply(set) - df['B'].apply(set)).astype(bool)
0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
16     True
17     True
18     True
19     True
dtype: bool
```

To get the union:

```
df['intersection'] = [list(set(a).intersection(set(b))) 
                      for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]

>>> df
                     A                                      B        intersection
0              [gener]                               [gutter]                  []
1              [gener]                               [gutter]                  []
2             [system]                       [gutter, system]            [system]
3             [system]                [gutter, guard, system]            [system]
4             [gutter]                         [ohio, gutter]            [gutter]
5             [gutter]                       [gutter, toledo]            [gutter]
6             [gutter]                       [toledo, gutter]            [gutter]
7             [gutter]                               [gutter]            [gutter]
8             [gutter]                               [gutter]            [gutter]
9             [gutter]                               [gutter]            [gutter]
10          [aluminum]    [how, to, instal, aluminum, gutter]          [aluminum]
11          [aluminum]                     [aluminum, gutter]          [aluminum]
12          [aluminum]              [aluminum, gutter, color]          [aluminum]
13          [aluminum]                     [aluminum, gutter]          [aluminum]
14          [aluminum]       [aluminum, gutter, adrian, ohio]          [aluminum]
15          [aluminum]  [aluminum, gutter, bowl, green, ohio]          [aluminum]
16          [aluminum]        [aluminum, gutter, maume, ohio]          [aluminum]
17          [aluminum]   [aluminum, gutter, perrysburg, ohio]          [aluminum]
18          [aluminum]     [aluminum, gutter, tecumseh, ohio]          [aluminum]
19  [aluminum, toledo]       [aluminum, gutter, toledo, ohio]  [aluminum, toledo]
```

Comment: Exactly the one-liners and knowledge I was hoping to achieve from this question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `apply` function supported by `pandas`, it's great.

Since you may have more than two columns for intersecting, the auxiliary function can be prepared like this and then applied with the `DataFrame.apply` function (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html, note the option `axis=1` means "across the series" while `axis=0` means "along the series", where one
series is just one column in the data frame). Each row across the columns is then passed as a iterable `Series` object to the function applied.

```
def intersect(ss):
    ss = iter(ss)
    s = set(next(ss))
    for t in ss:
        s.intersection_update(t) # `t' must not be a `set' here, `list' or any `Iterable` is OK
    return s

res = df.apply(intersect, axis=1)

>>> res
0                     {}
1                     {}
2               {system}
3               {system}
4               {gutter}
5               {gutter}
6               {gutter}
7               {gutter}
8               {gutter}
9               {gutter}
10            {aluminum}
11            {aluminum}
12            {aluminum}
13            {aluminum}
14            {aluminum}
15            {aluminum}
16            {aluminum}
17            {aluminum}
18            {aluminum}
19    {aluminum, toledo}
```

You can augment further operations on the result of the auxiliary function, or make some variations similarly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First time I've ever seen `intersection_update` before.  Very interesting code!  Thanks for a great alternative to learn from.

Comment: @Jarad Glad you like it. There are quite a lot of useful built-in operations for Python container types. It is sometimes funny to explore them in the docs :)